# I can print the memory with gdb's x command ,but if I use printf,segmentation fault

Tags: c, gdb

This line is causing segfault to me:

```
30              printf("st_name:\t%s\n", &p_str_tab[p->st_name]);
```

I've tried to trace it down in gdb:

```
(gdb) p p_str_tab[p->st_name]
$11 = 0 '\000'
(gdb) p &p_str_tab[p->st_name]
$12 = 0x2aaaaaab0000 ""
(gdb) x/16s 0x2aaaaaab0000
0x2aaaaaab0000:  ""
0x2aaaaaab0001:  ".symtab"
0x2aaaaaab0009:  ".strtab"
(gdb) call printf("st_name:\t%s\n", 0x2aaaaaab0000)

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000034f4042729 in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
```

I can print the memory with gdb's `x` command ,but if I use printf,segmentation fault.

Why?

UPDATE as required in comment:

```
(gdb) x/1i $rip 
0x34f4042729 <vfprintf+57>: mov    0xc0(%rdi),%eax
(gdb) info reg 
rax            0x54 84
rbx            0x34f3e1bbc0 227429956544
rcx            0x0  0
rdx            0xffffffffffffffb0   -80
rsi            0x401b08 4201224
rdi            0x600908 6293768
rbp            0x7fffffffe6e0   0x7fffffffe6e0
rsp            0x7fffffffe040   0x7fffffffe040
r8             0x2aaaaaabf210   46912496202256
r9             0x34f4351780 227435419520
r10            0x1238   4664
r11            0x648    1608
r12            0x0  0
r13            0x7fffffffe9c0   140737488349632
r14            0x0  0
r15            0x0  0
rip            0x34f4042729 0x34f4042729 <vfprintf+57>
eflags         0x10202  [ IF RF ]
cs             0x33 51
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
fctrl          0x37f    895
fstat          0x0  0
ftag           0xffff   65535
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
fiseg          0x0  0
fioff          0x0  0
foseg          0x0  0
fooff          0x0  0
fop            0x0  0
mxcsr          0x1f80   [ IM DM ZM OM UM PM ]
```

Comment: it would help to see the interested code, in particular what `&p_str_tab[p->st_name]` is; gdb `p`s should help, but I can't see strageness in effect, surely missing something; about x, is it possible gdb can read safely more memory than the program itself can access? I should check

Comment: @ShinTakezou ,`&p_str_tab[p->st_name]` points to the symbol table at `0x2aaaaaab0000` as printed above.

Comment: Can you do a `x/1i $rip` and `info reg` after SEGV?

Comment: are you trying to access the elf of the program you are running?

Comment: Also a `cat /proc/<pid>/maps` for the debugged process while it's running, lest the ELF info be `mprotect()`ed by gdb.

Comment: This sounds interesting and could be a flaw in the compiler.  I'd appreciate seeing a short, self-contained, compilable example for reproducing it (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @ninjalj ,I've updated with the info .

Comment: If you change the line of code to `printf("st_name:\t%s\n", "constant");`, does that segfault? If so, my best guess is you overran a pointer somewhere; try valgrind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be a pointer overran issue ,try valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check whether you're overflowing the stack.

Comment: Since the faulting instruction does not reference stack, stack overflow is exceedingly unlikely to have anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The faulting instruction `mov    0xc0(%rdi),%eax` represents something like `eax = rdi->member` where `member` is at offset 0xc0.  Without seeing more disassembly it's hard to know what that is for sure, but it seems likely that it's `stdout` or something inside `stdout`.  It's not likely that the faulting instruction is dereferencing your input string.

Have you done anything unusual to `stdout`?  A brute force approach would be to sprinkle `printf` everywhere (of what it probably doesn't matter) and see where it starts crashing.  Just before that is where something got corrupted.